# Why do some URLs not followed with "follow-redirects" npm package?

Tags: node.js

I'm creating a node.js app where I have a list of URLs and I want to verify that the URLs resolve to their actual address and are not redirected.

I'm using this npm package ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/follow-redirects )
as it's the only one I've found that purports to follow redirects in URLs.

I've included a stripped down version of the part of the app I'm building.

I've included three URLs here, the second and third (currently commented out), behave as expected, whereas the first one throws an error.

```
const { http, https } = require("follow-redirects");

const url = {
    host: "thebookdepository.co.uk", // 1. This one should resolve to https://www.bookdepository.com/ but fails
  //   host: "theguardian.co.uk", // 2. This one resolves to https://www.theguardian.com/international
  //   host: "bitly.com",  path: "/3FjTVHx", // 3. This resolves to https://www.bookdepository.com/
};

const request = https.request(url, (response) => {
  console.log(response.responseUrl);
});
request.end();
```

The first URL when entered into a web browser resolves to "https://www.bookdepository.com/" but the node app throws the following error:

```
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 94.136.40.82:443
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1107:14)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at ClientRequest.eventHandlers.(anonymous function) (/Users/username/apache_server/follow-redirects/node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:14:24)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:401:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Is there something different about the way https://www.bookdepository.co.uk/ does its redirects? And why does the script not follow it?

Any helpful tips or hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok – I've found the answer. The URLs that throw an error do not use HTTPS but HTTP. I changed the protocol and URL number 1 resolves too.

`http.request` vs `https.request`